# Sharepoint 2010 & InfoPath: How to deploy a customized list form as a feature?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath, wsp

in SharePoint 2010 it is quite easy to customize and publish the standard lists forms to a local server. But how do I deploy the forms as a feature to be installed on the customer's SharePoint farm?
I would like to include the form in a feature which creates the lists (programmatically in the feature receiver, not with a list template), is that possible?

Thank you for any hints!

Stephan

Answer (score 0):

Create your list definition in Visual Studio 2010 using the SharePoint project template and deploy it as a feature. Check out MSDN on how to create list definitions and features in VS 2010

Comment: I rather create the list programmatically in the feature receiver. But how do I include the form in that feature?

Comment: How about some links to MSDN articles that show how to do this, and how to add the IP form to the list?